# invalid uri: stomp://0.0.0.0:61613 [invalid broker(s): 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'groupdict']

Tags: activemq-classic, python-3.6, stomp

I am trying to connect to my local ActiveMQ. On connection attempt I get the following message:

> invalid uri: stomp://0.0.0.0:61613 [invalid broker(s): 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'groupdict']

My **activemq.xml** has following enteries

```xml
<transportConnectors>
    <!-- DOS protection, limit concurrent connections to 1000 and frame size to 100MB -->
    <transportConnector name="openwire" uri="tcp://0.0.0.0:61616?maximumConnections=1000&amp;wireFormat.maxFrameSize=104857600"/>
    <transportConnector name="amqp" uri="amqp://0.0.0.0:5672?maximumConnections=1000&amp;wireFormat.maxFrameSize=104857600"/>
    <transportConnector name="stomp" uri="stomp://0.0.0.0:61613?maximumConnections=1000&amp;wireFormat.maxFrameSize=104857600"/>
    <transportConnector name="mqtt" uri="mqtt://0.0.0.0:1883?maximumConnections=1000&amp;wireFormat.maxFrameSize=104857600"/>
    <transportConnector name="ws" uri="ws://0.0.0.0:61614?maximumConnections=1000&amp;wireFormat.maxFrameSize=104857600"/>
</transportConnectors>
```

and this is my code

```
def copy_activemq_to_s3():
    """

    :param environment_config:
    :param entity_config:
    :param entity_name:
    :return:
    """

    uri = "stomp://0.0.0.0:61613"
    user_name = "system"
    password = "manager"
    queue = "my_queue"
    connection = stormpest_conn(uri, user_name, password)

    # write_message(connection, queue)
    read_message(connection, queue)


def stormpest_conn(uri, user_name, password):
    config = StompConfig(
        uri=uri,
        login=user_name,
        passcode=password,
        sslContext=sslContext
    )

    client = Stomp(config)
    client.connect(connectTimeout=10000, connectedTimeout=10000)

    return client
```

Now I don't know what's causing it connect to ActiveMQ?

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the STOMPest (?) client documentation it is pretty obvious that you are using the wrong URI.  The stomp URI scheme is incorrect as per the examples as documented [here](http://nikipore.github.io/stompest/).  The client documentation I've been able to find would indicate that you want to use a URI scheme of 'tcp' or 'ssl' depending on which you want to use as the transport.

Comment: So for SSL do i need to have SSL cert? when testing on local